# Android Polyline - Adding point by point

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I'm currently having a map, and each 10 meters I use LocationListener to refresh my location and get the new Latitude and Longitude. Now I wish that the route the user is taking will be displayed with a red line. So everytime the OnLocationChange() from LocationListener class is called, I want to update the map with a line between the last location and the new location.

So far I've added the following:

```
private void initializeDraw() {
    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);
    lineRoute = workoutMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
}
```

during the OnLocationChanged I call this:

```
drawTrail();
```

now what should I insert into this function so that each time it adds the newly attained location as a point and draws a line from the last to the new point.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First translate `Location` into `LatLng`:

```
LatLng newPoint = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

Then add a point to existing list of points:

```
List<LatLng> points = lineRoute.getPoints();
points.add(newPoint);
lineRoute.setPoints(points);
```