# Polylines are not filled correctly on google map v2 on android

Tags: android, dictionary, polyline

I am trying to draw polylines while i'm walking/driving(connecting point by point) but it comes out messy([Image link](http://tinypic.com/r/2mozb87/8)). I read the recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157454/android-polyline-adding-point-by-point) and did some research, and I came up with the below code to do that:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

I start from the initializeDraw() first:

```
private void initializeDraw(){
    rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);
    newPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}
```

And than I start the OnLocationListener (using network_provider):

```
RTlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, drawLocationOnMap);
```

The locationListener (from which i'm updating the points(lat/lng and focusing the cam on the location):

```
LocationListener drawLocationOnMap = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        LatLng newPoint = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        points = newPolyline.getPoints();
        points.add(newPoint);
        newPolyline.setPoints(points);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .zoom(18)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(70)
                .build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    };
};
```

The result:
[Image link](http://tinypic.com/r/2mozb87/8)

By looking at the image above, it looks like a "zigzag" even though I walked a straight 100m line . Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it. After getting the accuracy (using    getAccuracy()    ) I figured that sometimes it is more than 1000m . after some thoughts I decided to rewrite my location updates using LocationClient rather then LocationManager since it is more accurate by using a combination of the GPS provider and network provider.

I followed the official LocationClient guide [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Comment: Have you finally set the condition for Accuracy < 1000m to work? I am having the same issue, need to know what Accuracy parameter should I use for accurate polyline drawing results?